# Woocommerce new order notification to different email based on shipping country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Been pulling my hair out over this for a few days now. The scenario is that 1 store has 2 locations so based on the shipping country selected at checkout the new order notification needs to go to the relevant email address.

I got this to work....partially.

During testing phase I used "direct bank transfer" payment method for the sake of getting the order completed. The below code works great with that payment method but as i discovered later when an order gets placed through paypal it no longer works.

Futhermore, if you change the product to virtual then it works with paypal, but as soon as you add

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', '__return_true' );
```

to bring back the shipping options then it stops working again.

Here is my code so far

```
    global $woocommerce;
if (strtolower($woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country()) === 'us') {
$this->send( 'shopone@gmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
} else {
$this->send( 'shoptwo@gmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
};
```

Hopefully someone can spot something obvious that I am missing, thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Zapier works but has some limitations, I would still like to find a solution to this that doesnt require a third party app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

For anyone with the same problem in future, in class-wc-email-new-order.php replace

```
$this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
```

with

```
if ($this->object->shipping_country === 'US') {
$this->send( 'shopeone@gmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
} else { 
$this->send( 'shoptwo@email.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
}
```

The problem was using the $woocommerce global to grab the value from the customer when you should be grabbing the value from the order itself.

If you want to create a conditional based on a different checkout field you can find the list in class-wc-api-orders.php

Just replace

```
 $order->shipping_country
```

With

```
$this->object->shipping_country
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative way to accomplish this using a site called [Zapier](https://zapier.com/).  It allows you to link up multiple APIs, one of which is WooCommerce.  All you would need to do is create a trigger that would send an email to shopone@gmail.com if the Shipping Country was US, and shoptwo@gmail.com if it wasn't, regardless of payment method.

Comment: Thanks zapier achieved what I needed to do!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I thought it solved my problem but zapier wasn't flexible enough with the actual email content which was important to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This works better than any other option that I have seen, thanks!
I changed the `shipping_country` for `billing_state`.

Is it possible to add more than two variants? Let say something like:

```
    if ($this->object->billing_state === 'SC') {
    $this->send( 
        'sc@gmail.com', 
        $this->get_subject(),     
        $this->get_content(), 
        $this->get_headers(), 
        $this->get_attachments()
    ); 
}

    if ($this->object->billing_state === 'RS') {
        $this->send( 
            'rs@gmail.com', 
            $this->get_subject(),
            $this->get_content(), 
            $this->get_headers(), 
            $this->get_attachments() 
        );
    } 

if ($this->object->billing_state === 'PR') {
        $this->send( 
            'pr@gmail.com', 
            $this->get_subject(),
            $this->get_content(), 
            $this->get_headers(), 
            $this->get_attachments() 
        );
    } 


    else { 
        $this->send( 
            'else@gmail.com',
            $this->get_subject(), 
            $this->get_content(), 
            $this->get_headers(), 
            $this->get_attachments() 
        );
    }
```

Comment: I think a closing braket si missing!

Comment: I did not found the missing brasket (I'm a newbie).
"Else" e-mail is not working also

My code:

`if ($this->object->billing_state === 'SC') {
$this->send( 'scc@gmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
} 

if ($this->object->billing_state === 'RS') {
$this->send( 'rs@gmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
} 

else { 
$this->send( 'else@hotmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
}`

Comment: I redid the indentation of the code. As you can see, the last "}" is missing. But actually, I think it is before the second if(){ ... }

I will post and answer.

Comment: I ended up modifying just a little bit, the checkout was not being completed because I think after the first "if" there was a missing "}". After I added it, things went ok, and now is working fully! Thanks a lot!

The only thing is that whenever I send a mail to the second "if" the "else" e-mail receives the notification too, but thats not a major deal, I can live with that.

Comment: Glad to have helped.
This is why it is very important to ensure the proper indentation of the code. This solves 80% of the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried applying the code to allow for conditional emails based on a custom checkout field - select with two values. As described and no emails went out.

```
if ($this->object->billing_divisions === 'sprinkler') {
  $this->send( 'shopeone@gmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
} else { 
  $this->send( 'shoptwo@mail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
}
```

I edited the php file again to add back the replaced code. Otherwise new order emails are not triggered for admin.

```
if ( $this->is_enabled() && $this->get_recipient() ) {
```

I've been racking my brain trying to get conditional emails working based on a custom checkout field selection.

Comment: This still isn't working.  I replaced  if ( $this->is_enabled() && $this->get_recipient() ) {  with

Comment: I replaced  if ( $this->is_enabled() && $this->get_recipient() ) {  with    if ($this->object->billing_divisions === 'sprinkler') {
  $this->send( 'shopeone@gmail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
} else { 
  $this->send( 'shoptwo@mail.com', $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
}     as shown, in the class-wc-email-new-order.php file.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_new_order', 'new_order_conditional_email_recipient', 10, 2 );
function new_order_conditional_email_recipient( $recipient, $order ) {
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
    $custom_field = get_post_meta($order_id, 'custom_field', true);
    if ($custom_field == "value1") 
        $recipient .= ', xxxxxervices@gmail.com'; 
    elseif ($custom_field == "value2") 
        $recipient .= ', xxxxxshoponline@gmail.com';
    return $recipient; }

Tested and working Woocommerce Version 3.3.3